# Comments numbering on multiple pages

Tags: comments

I have a problem with the numbering of my comments when they extend to more than one page. On the new page the numbering starts from again from 1. Also, on page 2 the pingbacks/trackbacks don't appear anymore.

This is the code I'm using in `comments.php`:

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h3 class="com"><span class="com-titlu"><?php comments_number('Niciun comentariu', 'Un comentariu', '% comentarii' );?></span> la: <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <ol class="commentlist">
        <?php wp_list_comments(array(
          'callback'=>'advanced_comment',
          'style'=>'ol',
          'type'=>'comment'
          ));
        ?>
    </ol>
    <?php 
      if ( $num = t5_count_pings() )
        {
    ?>
     <h3 id="pingbacks">
       <?php printf( _n( 'One pingback', '%d pingbacks', $num, 't5_theme' ), $num ); ?>
     </h3>
    <ol class="pingback">
    <?php wp_list_comments(array (
            'type'     => 'pings',
            'style'    => 'ul',
            'callback' => 'list_pings'
        ));
    ?></ol>
    <?php } ?>
```

And these are the functions I used in `functions.php`:

```
<?php function advanced_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
   $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
   <div class="comment-author vcard">
     <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='48',$default='<path_to_url>' ); ?>
       <div class="comment-meta"<a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url'); ?>"><?php printf(__('%s'), get_comment_author_link()) ?></a> 
       <span class="com-date"> a scris pe: <small><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','') ?></small></span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
       <em><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em><br />
     <?php endif; ?>
     <div class="comment-text"> 
         <?php comment_text() ?>
     </div>
   <div class="reply">
      <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php add_filter('get_comments_number', 'comment_count', 0);
function comment_count( $count ) {
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
global $id;
$comments_by_type = &separate_comments(get_comments('status=approve&post_id=' . $id));
return count($comments_by_type['comment']);
} else {
return $count;
}
}
?>
<?php 
/**
 * Count amount of pingbacks + trackbacks for a post.
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID for comment query. Default is current post.
 * @return int
 */
function t5_count_pings( $post_id = NULL )
{
    $pings    = 0;
    $comments = FALSE;
    if ( NULL !== $post_id )
    {
        $comments = get_comments(
            array (
                'post_id' => $post_id, # Note: post_ID will not work!
                'status'  => 'approve'
            )
        );
    }
    elseif ( ! empty ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->comments ) )
    {
        $comments = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->comments;
    }
    if ( ! $comments )
        return 0;
    foreach ( $comments as $c )
        if ( in_array ( $c->comment_type, array ( 'pingback', 'trackback' ) ) )
            $pings += 1; 
    return $pings;
}
?>
```

Problems: 
1) Trackbacks and pingbacks don't appear on each page of comments. 
2) The numbering of comments starts over on each new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the numbering, you'll have to modify the first code to reset numbering via CSS. This way (untested, but you'll catch the idea ;) ).

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h3 class="com"><span class="com-titlu"><?php comments_number('Niciun comentariu', 'Un comentariu', '% comentarii' );?></span> la: <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php $number = intval(get_query_var( 'cpage' )) * intval(get_query_var( 'comments_per_page' )) - intval( get_query_var( 'comments_per_page' ) ); ?>
    <ol class="commentlist" style="counter-reset: item <?php echo $number; ?>">
        <?php wp_list_comments...
```

The idea of used algorithm for getting starting number is that if your are on page 2 displaying 5 comments per page, you'll start with 6.

Than to determine the first number, you have to multiply the page number (2) with comments per page (5) - you'll get a result of 10.

The first number have to be 6, so you'll have to subtract comments per page (5) from the result and use the final result as `{ counter-reset: item FINAL_RESULT }`

CSS starts numbering from a number following after the one used in this rule. So 5 is OK.

2*5-5 = 5 => starts with 6

3*5-5 = 10 => starts with 11

If you need the reverse numbering, this is going to be much more complicated as CSS probably does not offer a solution. But you can check [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438864/reversing-ol-numbering). Also the algorithm for determining first number is going to be different.

Comment: Your script is working, i can see the counter in firebug but I think I have some problems with the CSS. The problem is that I can get the numbering to work correctly. This is the code I've used: `.depth-1:before { content: "" counter(item, decimal) "."; counter-increment: item 1; }`. As a result each comment has the number "1." in front.

Comment: It would help if I had an option to see the outputed HTML and CSS somewhere - jsfidlle?

Comment: I solved it in the meantime. Thanks for helping, like I said, the script worked great!